# Adding third party libraries to jHipster 4.x App

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

I created an app using jHipster 4.0.0 with Angular 2 / Typescript under Ubuntu 16.04.
Now I want to use [visjs](http://visjs.org) in my app.

I followed a simple appoach similar to this [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/TbPTfXFk4RSAuPn4BBxP?p=preview), but I don't want to explicity add a `script`-tag for this to the *index.html* page, but package it together with the other Javascript libraries (that jHipster is using out of the box).

In the jHipster documentation (*Using in Development*) *bower* is mentioned - so I did *bower init* and installed the *vis* dependency. Then it is mentioned that the gulp server has to be started, but there is no gulp file.

When I just start the app, then the Browser Console prints this error:
*vis is not defined*

I'm doing something wrong - can anyone give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: bower is used only for angular 1, follow example in the README of your generated project.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks that was a useful hint! I processed the described steps and it seems that _visjs_ is included in vendor.dll.js - at least vendor.json now contains that snippet:

` "./node_modules/vis/dist/vis.js": {
      "id": 441,
      "meta": {}
    }`

But the browser still complains about undefined _vis_.
It works when I add it directly to index.html:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.18.1/vis.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.18.1/vis.min.css" />`

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/brechtbilliet/angular-typescript-webpack